# Node net.socket.client too many connections error

Tags: node.js, windows, electron

I'm using net.socket.client to create connections as many as possible in electron on win7 platform.Here is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  var net = require('net');
  var client = new net.Socket();
  client.connect(8080,'http://xxx.xx',function() {
  client.write('somedata\n');
  });
}
```

when I run this code on my win7 , some error fired

```
1.Error: connect EMFILE xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 - Local (undefined:undefined)
2.Error: This socket has been ended by the other party.
3.Error: This socket connect EINVAL XX.XX.XX.XX:8080 - local(0.0.0.0:58983)
```

just about 5000 connection has been accepted, Am I wrong? or something should be setting to unlock the limit on win7.by the way I searched google about win7 tcp limit and found win7 has no tcp count limit.

Comment: This error looks like the other end you are connecting to closed the socket.  That's probably where the limit is in this case (on the other end).  But, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  Making 5000 simultaneous connections to the same host from the same client is not a likely real world situation.

Comment: you are right ,it's not common situation,I'm developing a tool for simulating users on a live site to improve the online user count.you mean the remote server has limit for the same client(same Ip but different port)?

Comment: I mean that servers often have a limit to the number of simultaneous connections that they will support.  They may or not may have attack protection that limits connections from the same IP - that depends entirely upon their infrastructure.